# Remove array duplicates PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

How do I remove duplicates from an array?

Let's say that my I have two arrays named `$array` and `$new_array`. `$array` has contents while `$new_array` is empty, as seen below:

```
$array = array(5,1,2,1,5,7,10);
$new_array = array();
```

I want `$new_array` to store the unique values of `$array`. It kind of goes like this:

```
$array = array(5,1,2,1,5,7,10);
$new_array = array(5,1,2,7,10); // removing the 1 and 5 after 2 since those numbers are already a duplicate of the preceding numbers.
echo $new_array; // Output: 512710
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a cursory Google search would give you the answer a thousand-fold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through PHP's [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function.

This function traverses through your provided array and returns an array with unique values (repeating values will be removed).

Code to return desired string:

```
$array = array(5,1,2,1,5,7,10);
$new_array = array_unique($array);
echo implode('', $new_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$array = array(5,1,2,1,5,7,10);
$new_array = array_unique($array);
echo implode('', $new_array);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/52956):

```
512710
```

Comment: OMG thanks! So does that mean that $new_array now stores the unique values of $array?