# Overwrite foreach output if duplicate value exists

Tags: php, string

I've a folder on server, m fetching those files but getting some difficulties. my code is

```
$dir = 'F:\\wamp\www\files';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if(($file = scandir($dir))!==false) {    

    foreach ($file as $key => $value) {                  
        $name = substr($value,0,-7);
```

the scandir()  function retuns array of files which returns list of names, i.e.

```
manoj254.txt
manoj234.txt
pooza145.txt
pooza452.txt
ramesh418.txt
ramesh231.txt
```

and i've remove the extension by using substr() function after this the output is $name

```
manoj
manoj
pooza
pooza
ramesh
ramesh
```

But i need the output $name, without duplicate.i.e

```
manoj
pooza
ramesh
```

which means remove duplicates... can any body help me plz !!

Comment: See [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove array duplicates PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207326/remove-array-duplicates-php)

Comment: sorry for wrng description dude..... can u plz rewrite ur opinion

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
function getUniqueFileNames($path = null)
{
    if($path && $files = scandir($path)) { 
        $names = array_map(function($i) {
            if(is_file($i)) return str_replace(strrchr($i, '.'), '', $i);
        }, $files);
        return array_unique(array_filter($names));
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
$filenames = getUniqueFileNames('F:\\wamp\www\files');
```

There are other ways though.

Comment: No it works (tested), just make sure you have did it the right way.